# Get metrics of an Azure vm in c#

Tags: c#, azure, virtual-machine, metrics

I have the code below that retrieves CPU Percentage of an Azure vm.
I want the metrics for Network In, Network Out, Disk Read Bytes, Disk Write Bytes, Disk Read Operations, Disk Write Operation.  It doesn't seem to matter what I put for queryString, I always get cpu percentage.  How can I get the other metrics?

```
private void test()
{
    string vmName = "myVM";
    string resourceId = "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupWest/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/" + vmName;
    var subscriptionId = "mySubscriptionID";
    var clientId = "myClientID";
    var secret = "myKey";
    var tenantId = "myTenantID";
    resourceId = resourceId.Replace("{subscriptionId}", subscriptionId);

    MonitorClient readOnlyClient = AuthenticateWithReadOnlyClient(tenantId, clientId, secret, subscriptionId).Result;

    string queryString = "name.value eq 'CpuPercentage'";
    ODataQuery<MetadataValue> odataQuery = new ODataQuery<MetadataValue>(queryString);
    var vals = readOnlyClient.Metrics.List(resourceId, odataQuery );
    foreach (MetricValue v in vals.Value[0].Timeseries[0].Data)
    {
        if (v.Average != null)
        {
            totalAverage += v.Average.Value;
        }
    }
    totalAverage = totalAverage / vals.Value[0].Timeseries[0].Data.Count;
}

private static async Task<MonitorClient> AuthenticateWithReadOnlyClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string secret, string subscriptionId)
{
    // Build the service credentials and Monitor client            
    var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, secret);            
    var monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds);           
    monitorClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;            
    return monitorClient;        
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into what Azure offers by itself? There's a lot of resources that do for you what you're describing.

Comment: Can you post a link? I don't really care how I get this data.  I'm having a really hard time finding sample code.

Comment: Well I can't give you a concrete starting point because it's been a while since I've done something like that. However I did some minor googling and I found stuff like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-diagnostics-template. If it's not what youre looking for, just do some more research before you reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Don't forget to close or remove your question ;)

Comment: I was hoping to get some more responses.  I won't forget to close this.

Comment: Please take a look at the following sample: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't seem to matter what I put for queryString, I always get cpu percentage. How can I get the other metrics?

You could get the other metrics name from [Supported metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines).
If you want to get multiple metrics you could use **or** to append the metrics. The CPU metrics is the default metrics of Azure VM

```
 var queryString = "(name.value eq 'Disk Write Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Percentage CPU' or  name.value eq 'Network In' or  name.value eq 'Network Out' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Bytes' or  name.value eq 'Disk Write Bytes')";
```

I also do a demo before, more detail please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950222/azure-microsoft-insights-api-2016-09-01-error-while-collecting-metrics/46971750#46971750).

```
var azureTenantId = "tenant id";
var azureSecretKey = "secret key";
var azureAppId = "client id";
var subscriptionId = "subscription id";
var resourceGroup = "resource group";
var machineName = "machine name";
var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(azureTenantId, azureAppId, azureSecretKey).Result;
MonitorClient monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
 var resourceUrl = $"subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{machineName}";
 var metricNames = "(name.value eq 'Disk Write Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Percentage CPU' or  name.value eq 'Network In' or  name.value eq 'Network Out' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Bytes' or  name.value eq 'Disk Write Bytes')"; 
 string timeGrain = " and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'";
 string startDate = " and startTime eq 2017-10-26T05:28:34.919Z";
 string endDate = " and endTime eq 2017-10-26T05:33:34.919Z";
 var odataFilterMetrics = new ODataQuery<MetricInner>(
                $"{metricNames}{timeGrain}{startDate}{endDate}");

 var metrics = monitorClient.Metrics.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceUrl, odataFilterMetrics).Result;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I still get only cpu percentage but at least I now know what to put to get other values.  I'll have to troubleshoot on my end now.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?  You could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950222/azure-microsoft-insights-api-2016-09-01-error-while-collecting-metrics/46971750#46971750) to get my test result.

Comment: Yes, I got it work, just as you have it in your answer.  I had to get around some user-error issues.  Do I close this or just leave it with the answer above?  I don't see a button to close this.