# Is it possible to stream Azure VM metrics to an eventhub without touching the machine?

Tags: azure, stream, virtual-machine, metrics, azure-eventhub

I am currently trying to stream metrics of a Azure Windows VM (like cpu etc) to an eventhub.
I found a tutorial under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-streaming-azure-diags-data, but in this tutorial it is necessary to change the configuration of each system. Since we got a lot of systems, this would mean a major inconvenience. The only metrics we currently need are those shown when clicking on the VM in Azure (PERCENTAGE CPU, NETWORK IN/OUT, DISK READ/WRITE BYTES, DISK READ OPERATIONS). we allready managed to send alerts based on those metrics via a logic app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to stream Azure VM metrics to an eventhub without touching the machine?

Yes, we could get the metric with [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent/1.3.0-beta/)t. You could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099715/get-metrics-of-an-azure-vm-in-c-sharp/48106772#48106772) to get the demo code. We also could get more other supported metrics name from [Supported metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines).

```
var azureTenantId = "tenant id";
var azureSecretKey = "secret key";
var azureAppId = "client id";
var subscriptionId = "subscription id";
var resourceGroup = "resource group";
var machineName = "machine name";
var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(azureTenantId, azureAppId, azureSecretKey).Result;
MonitorClient monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
 var resourceUrl = $"subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{machineName}";
 var metricNames = "(name.value eq 'Disk Write Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Percentage CPU' or  name.value eq 'Network In' or  name.value eq 'Network Out' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Operations/Sec' or  name.value eq 'Disk Read Bytes' or  name.value eq 'Disk Write Bytes')"; 
 string timeGrain = " and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'";
 string startDate = " and startTime eq 2017-10-26T05:28:34.919Z";
 string endDate = " and endTime eq 2017-10-26T05:33:34.919Z";
 var odataFilterMetrics = new ODataQuery<MetricInner>(
                $"{metricNames}{timeGrain}{startDate}{endDate}");

 var metrics = monitorClient.Metrics.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceUrl, odataFilterMetrics).Result;
```

And how to send the message to event hub, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send).